# Regexp Meta Description

Tags: regex, vbscript, asp-classic, regex-negation, regexp-like

When i use this regex on https://regex101.com `(<meta[^>]*description[^>]([^<]+)>)` its run.

```
Match 1
Full match  265-314 `<meta name="description" content="Stackoverflow">`
Group 1.    265-314 `<meta name="description" content="Stackoverflow">`
Group 2.    289-313 ` content="Stackoverflow"
```

but when i use this on my page its not run.

```
Function GetFirstMatch(PatternToMatch, StringToSearch)
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = PatternToMatch
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.Global = True
    regEx.MultiLine = True
    Set CurrentMatches = regEx.Execute(StringToSearch)

    GetFirstMatch = ""
    If CurrentMatches.Count >= 1 Then
        Set CurrentMatch = CurrentMatches(0)
        If CurrentMatch.SubMatches.Count >= 1 Then
            GetFirstMatch = CurrentMatch.SubMatches(0)
        End If
    End If
    Set regEx = Nothing
End Function

GetFirstMatch("(<meta[^>]*description[^>]([^<]+)>)",sdatai)
```

thank you

Comment: What is in ``sdatai``?

Comment: sdatai=pagehtmlcode

Comment: Please give an example of ``sdatai``.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>My first HTML document</TITLE>
<meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description. This will often show up in search results.">
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <P>Hello world!
   </BODY>
</HTML>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have the word "description" inside the content. This causes the first part of the regex (`<meta[^>]*description`) to skip everything until the last occurrence of "description". Here's the regex that should fix this:

```
(<meta[\s]+name="description"[^>]([^>]+)>)
```